# Alertdialog ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error

Tags: android, arrays, exception, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to show an `AlertDialog` with some numbers that I get from a server. Displaying works. And it also goes to the next activity. It works on my android device, but on some it gives an exception and the phone crashes.

I always get this exception in logcat:

> D/Exception﹕ java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=-1

This is my code:

```
private void showOrderPopup(){
    try{
        materialLoaderOdoo = new MaterialLoaderOdoo();
        dbOrderModel = new DbOrderModel(context);
        Integer partnerId  = dbOrderModel.getPartnerIdByReference(Name);

        final List<Integer> listResults = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> result = dbOrderModel.getOrderById(Integer.parseInt(partnerId.toString()));;
        if(result.size() > 1){
            int t = result.size();
            newArray = new String[result.size()];
            //newArray[0] = "565";
            //newArray[1] = "565";

            for(int d=0;d<result.size();d++){
                listResults.add(d,result.get(d));
            }


            for(int d=0;d<result.size();d++){

                String r = result.get(d).toString();
                newArray[d] = result.get(d).toString();
                System.out.println(newArray[d]);

            }



            AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(YardActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Select One Letter");
            int selected = selectedItem;
            builder.setSingleChoiceItems(
                    newArray,
                    selected,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                            selectedItem=which;
                            System.out.println(which);
                            String nam = listResults.get(which).toString();
                            materialLoaderOdoo.execute(nam);
                            //System.out.println(newArray[selectedItem].toString());
                            Toast.makeText(YardActivity.this,"Loading materials...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(YardActivity.this,"Loading materials...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            OrderId = listResults.get(0);
            String w = listResults.get(0).toString();
            materialLoaderOdoo.execute(w);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        AlertHandler alertHandler = new AlertHandler(YardActivity.this);
        alertHandler.ShowAlert(YardActivity.this,"Error","Something went wrong!");
        Log.d("Exception", e.toString());

    }
}
```

Anyone knows how to fix this exception? I tried many things but it still show up in my logcat..

Answer (score 0):

This type of exception always come when list size is 0 and we are trying to access the list...So you have to check that list you are using have data or not..

Answer (score 0):

Print the stack trace. Will help you check exactly which line.
To print stack trace in Logs, use `Log.d(TAG, MESSAGE, new Exception());`